# Leaflet - Interactive choropleth map over time

Tags: javascript, leaflet, interactive, geo, choropleth

I have data of, say, density over 30 districts from 2000 to 2010.
I'd like to make an interactive choropleth map for each year and then either use a slider (ideally) or a radio button to select between years.

I can get interactivity on the first year, but NOT on the layers for other years.
You can see a working [example here](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/gafa/edit?html,output), but let me put some details below:

For simplicity, consider just two years. `blocks1995` has the non-overlapping polygons BlockA and BlockB (the two districts) and `blocks1996` has the same blocks. They have a property called `density` that produces the choropleth:

```
var blocks1995 = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { "time": 1995, "density": 3.1, "nameB": "BlockA" },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[50.0, 29.0],[50.0, 29.99],[50.51, 29.99],[50.0, 29.0]]]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": { "time": 1995, "density": 1.1, "nameB": "BlockB" },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[50.01, 30.0],[50.52, 30.0],[50.52, 30.5]]]
        }
    }]
};

var blocks1996 = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {"year": 1996, "density": 2.2, "name": "BlockA" },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[50.0, 29.0],[50.0, 29.99],[50.51, 29.99]]]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {"year": 1996,"density": 1.2,"name": "BlockB"},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[50.01, 30.0],[50.52, 30.0],[50.52, 30.5]]]
        }
    }]
};
```

I've tried adding them to an  `OverlayLayer`

```
var blocks1995Layer = L.layerGroup([ L.geoJson(blocks1995)]),
    blocks1996Layer = L.layerGroup([ L.geoJson(blocks1996)]);


var overlayMaps = {
    "Blocks 1995": blocks1995Layer,
    "Blocks 1996": blocks1996Layer
};

var map = new L.map('map', {layers:[blocks1995Layer]})
    .setView([29, 50], 7);
```

I put the boilerplate interactivity code found in this [Leaflet interactive choropleth tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) and then I add back to the map:

```
geojson = L.geoJson(blocks1995, {
    style: density_style,
    onEachFeature: addToFeature
}).addTo(map);

L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

The problem is I'm adding interactivity to `blocks1995` only, but I haven't been able to add it to `overlayMaps`.

I'm OK using a Leaflet plug-in (I tried TimeSlider but also couldn't figure it out).

Another possibility is to combine the two `block1995`and `block1996` variables into one with an extra feature `year` or `time` is that makes things easier. The idea would be for Leaflet to query by time (say, when a slider moves) and produce the interactive choropleth per year.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to clearLayers() when you change years and add the new data. So basically you going to have one layer as in the choropleth tutorial but you clear it every time you update the year data.

Comment: Hi @AlexParij, where should I put `clearLayers()`?

Comment: The geometry for each year would remain same? I mean the total number of features and their location would remain same for each year?

Comment: @muzaffar Yes, they should remain the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you're not adding layers to control properly. Currently, you're doing this

```
var blocks1995Layer = L.layerGroup([ L.geoJson(blocks1995)]),
    blocks1996Layer = L.layerGroup([ L.geoJson(blocks1996)]);

var overlayMaps =  {
    "Blocks 1995": blocks1995Layer,
    "Blocks 1996": blocks1996Layer
};

geojson = L.geoJson(blocks1995, {
    style: density_style,
    onEachFeature: addToFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Instead, try this

```
geojson = L.geoJson(blocks1995, {
    style: density_style,
    onEachFeature: addToFeature
}).addTo(map);

geojson1 = L.geoJson(blocks1996, {
    style: density_style,
    onEachFeature: addToFeature
}).addTo(map);

var overlayMaps =  {
    "Blocks 1995": geojson,
    "Blocks 1996": geojson1
};
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/3cct20an/) is a working example

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/dub3Lj2v/) is another example where I've implemented radio buttons instead of checkboxes using [this](https://github.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol) plugin

**Edited**

As per your comment, I've created a example using [this](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) leaflet time slider plugin. Here is the part of the code.

```
//I've created 5 geojson layers, in order the slider to look appropriate.
geojson = L.geoJson(blocks1995, {
    style: density_style,
    onEachFeature: addToFeature,
    time: "1995" //this is for labeling, you may alter this value if required
});

geojson1 = L.geoJson(blocks1996, {
    style: density_style,
    onEachFeature: addToFeature,
    time: "1996"
});

geojson2 = L.geoJson(blocks1997, {
    style: density_style,
    onEachFeature: addToFeature,
    time: "1997"
});

geojson3 = L.geoJson(blocks1998, {
    style: density_style,
    onEachFeature: addToFeature,
    time: "1998"
});

geojson4 = L.geoJson(blocks1999, {
    style: density_style,
    onEachFeature: addToFeature,
    time: "1999"
});

//now add each geojson layer to a single layer group, as the slider take only one layer
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup([geojson, geojson1, geojson2, geojson3, geojson4 ]);

//initiate slider, follow = 1 means, show one feature at a time
var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({layer:layerGroup, follow: 1});
map.addControl(sliderControl);//add slider to map
sliderControl.startSlider();//starting slider
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/k49v3xmu/) is the working example

Comment: this is great, thanks so much! Would you be able to provide a Slider example based on your code?

Comment: great! I think a Slider would really look good with data over time

Comment: @cd98 .. I've added the slider example in the answer

Comment: great work, this will be helpful for other people too! For the slider example, you have some remnants from the group layered example that you can delete (var groups, var layerControl, and the addTo(groups.cities) part at the end)